# Proof with determinants and adjugates

Tags: linear-algebra

For an $n\times n$ matrix where $n>2$ how would one prove
$$\det\bigl(\operatorname{adj}\bigl(\operatorname{adj}(A)\bigr) = \det(A)^{(n-1)^2}.$$

any help to start this problem would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What’s your definition of the determinant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A.adj(A)=\det A. I_{n} \implies \det (adj(A))=(\det (A))^{n-1}$

$$ adj (A).adj(adj(A))=\det( adj (A)). I_{n} \implies \det(adj(adjA))=(\det (adj (A)))^{n-1}=(\det( A))^{(n-1)^2}$$